# Possible to call python class that uses concurrent.futures inside jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I find myself with the following structural problem :

I'm wanting to create a data handler class, which will store series of financial data I import. (These can take time, so I'd like to store it in the class attribute "cache" , to avoid re-download)

```
class DataHandler:
    self.cache = {} # store financial data for fast retrieval

def _create_multiple_processes_for_fast_io(symbs):
    if __name__ == "__main__": 
        pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

        # --> func is an IO function
        for item in pool.map(func, symbs):
            symb, series = item
            self.cache[symb] = series # save symbol data

def download_data(self, symbs)
    # download NEW stocks
    symbs_dwld = []
    for symb in symbs:
        if symb not in self.cache:
            symb_dwld.append(symb)

    # invoke multiple processes to read .csvs
    self._create_multiple_processes_for_fast_io(symb_dwld)
```

The problem is, we can't call concurrent.futures from jupyter notebook.

This is a problem because I dont know how many symbols I'll need to download up front (can't call this through the command line).

My question is, is there a way to call this class in a notebook? (the **name** == "**main**" currently fails) , or is it possible to call a concurrent.futures function multiple times instead of just once (eg., adding symbols as I go on).

And last, am I approaching this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this chunk of code in a .py file, say `mycode.py` with

```
if __name__ == __main__:
    ...(some code)...
```

at the end. The `(some code)` part should include the sequence of code you want to run. Then import this code into a Jupyter notebook, such as but not limited to,

```
from mycode import *
```

Then call the code sequence in the notebook. This can be done by defining a function `main()` to wrap around the code sequence and then run just `main()` in the notebook. Basically, type

```
main()
```

in a new cell in the notebook and execute (Shift + Enter).